# Setting hive configuration properties for Presto in EMR

Tags: hive, amazon-emr, presto

I'm trying to update hive connector properties inside `/etc/presto/conf/catalog/hive.properties`. I added the following:

```
hive.s3.max-client-retries=50
hive.s3.max-error-retries=50
hive.s3.max-connections=500
hive.s3.connect-timeout=5m
hive.s3.socket-timeout=5m
```

But for some reason these are not accepted. The presto server restart fails with the following error:

```
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   UNUSED PROPERTIES
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.connect-timeout
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.max-client-retries
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.max-connections
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.max-error-retries
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.socket-timeout
2018-04-16T19:34:26.369Z    WARN    main    Bootstrap   
2018-04-16T19:34:26.587Z    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'hive.s3.connect-timeout' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

2) Configuration property 'hive.s3.max-client-retries' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

3) Configuration property 'hive.s3.max-connections' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

4) Configuration property 'hive.s3.max-error-retries' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

5) Configuration property 'hive.s3.socket-timeout' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:234)

5 errors
```

Comment: What's the value of `hive.s3-file-system-type`? These properties are applicable when file system type is `PRESTO`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen your comment looks like an answer.

Comment: i converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

These properties are applicable when `hive.s3-file-system-type` is set to `PRESTO`. When it's eg. `EMRFS`, these configuration properties are not applicable and setting them causes the error you observe.

Comment: Thank Piotr. Is there any performance difference between Presto FS and EMRFS? I'm wondering if I should configure these properties in EMRFS or switch to Presto FS

Comment: @nish for performance considerations see a benchmark for Presto on EMR (using EMRFS) and Presto on EC2 (not using EMRFS). https://www.starburstdata.com/technical-blog/starburst-presto-on-aws-18x-faster-than-emr/ Some biggest differences can be attributed to CBO, but not all (we know in which queries CBO helps and in which it doesn't). For the benchmark, we tuned the EMR up from its default settings, as defaults were not yielding maximum performance. Disclaimer: i am from Starburst.

Answer (score 2):

As Piotr mentioned, EMR changed the default FileSystem implementation starting with emr-5.12.0 from PrestoS3FileSystem to EmrFS. PrestoS3FileSystem properties will be unavailable, but you can configure EmrFS as you would for any other application. See 'EMRFS and PrestoS3FileSystem Configuration' on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for adding this!